# Databinding CPU impact

Tags: android, android-databinding

Looking through some of the documentation and implementation of Google's Databinding library, it seems that inflating a layout to get a binding instance does not introduce much more operations than the standard view inflation. So I don't think using Databinding would have much impact on CPU usage upon view creation, compared to using something like ButterKnife view binding.

For using observables, the binding classes use propertyChange listeners under the hood. So I don't think observables would impact CPU usage vs manually adding listeners.

I believe using Databinding adds some small overhead in terms of operations but does not have a significant effect on runtime CPU usage. Is this correct to assume? Is there any more underlying operations that might impact performance?

Comment: Why are you worried? Would it affect your decision to use it? I'd say that there would be very little difference, of any, as the classes are generated at compile time, same with butterknife (why would you think butterknife adds cpu impact at runtime?).  The is no real wizardry going on, just generated classes at compile time based on the databinding annotations.  The only difference is probably compilation time, which is an acceptable overhead and increased method count.

Comment: I'm just curious. Don't think I said that butterknife add cpu impact. Most of the heavy lifting seems to be in compilation time. But bindings are inflated in runtime and that is not the same as view inflation. What I want to know is if the difference between the two is marginal and if there's anything else going on during runtime that's introduced by databinding.

Comment: If anything, you'll hear that databinding is more efficient at runtime than the traditional alternative of calling `findViewById`, perhaps repeatedly. As with many declarative solutions, though, it might be easier for you to inadvertently add inefficiencies. For example, if you have a ViewModel with many bound properties that updates frequently, but perhaps only certain properties change on any update. If you did `NotifyChange()` on every update instead of `NotifyPropertyChange` on the ones that actually did, you might unnecessarily be copying the same values to the view over and over again.